# CakePHP 3, variables in Internationalization / translation

Tags: variables, cakephp, internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.0

I want to use variables in some translation texts bu I can't figure out how to make it work. Your help would be appreciated.

**What I would Ideally like:**

In my page view:

`<?= __("welcome_message", ['John']) ?>` // or some variant

In my /en/default.po file

```
msgid "welcome_message"
msgstr "Welcome {1}, step in and have some fun!"
```

In short, how can I use a variable in a translated text? Thanks.

Comment: Markers are zero-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your view, the args are transfered to the translating function as an array, `{0}` takes the element at index `0` of your array passed in args

```
<?= __("Welcome {0}", ['John']) ?>
```

you can also use this syntax : where you pass variables as independent arguments to the function

```
<?= __("Welcome {0}", 'John') ?>
```

### [Using Variables in Translation Messages](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-variables-in-translation-messages)

Comment: And what would be my msgid in default.po?

Comment: Use [Peoedit](https://poedit.net/) to generate your translations files, it will be somrthing like :  ***msgid "Welcome {0}"*** \n
***msgstr "Bonjour {0}"***